# Processmaker 4 Community Edition Installation

Tags: node.js, installation

Require help to complete ProcessMaker4 installation process on a Centos 8 server. I currently stuck at 'npm run dev' step. There are error messages that I have no idea on how to fix it. Below are lines coppied from terminal.

[Error during `npm run dev`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nabdh.png)

Please assist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubles too.

I installed on Centos 7.7 and it works.

About npm, check you have installed NodeJS 10.x, mine is version 10.21.

To install it:

```html
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
```

This will install npm as well which in my case:

```html
npm --version
 
6.14.1
```

Comment: Many thanks. I have abandoned ProcessMaker4 and stick with version 3 for a while. I will try your recommendation when we decided to move to version 4.